# Read Handle info from array elements from buffer

Tags: firefox-addon, ctypes, jsctypes

I'm fetching handles and the structures are as follows:

```
var SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO = new ctypes.StructType('SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO', [
    {'UniqueProcessId': ctypes.unsigned_long},
    {'CreatorBackTraceIndex': ctypes.unsigned_long},
    {'ObjectTypeIndex': ctypes.unsigned_long},
    {'HandleAttributes': ctypes.unsigned_long},
    {'HandleValue': ctypes.unsigned_long},
    {'Object': ctypes.unsigned_long},
    {'GrantedAccess': ctypes.unsigned_long}
]);


var SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION = new ctypes.StructType('SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION', [
    {'NumberOfHandles': ctypes.unsigned_long},
    {'Handles': ctypes.ArrayType(SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO, 5)}
]);
```

So now I succesfully fetch `SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION` this is not the problem, I do this like this:

```
var proc = ctypes.cast(buffer.addressOfElement(0), SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION.ptr).contents;
```

This succesfully populates `proc` with this:

```
{NumberOfHandles: 59000, Handles:array}
```

Each element in `array` here is an object that looks like the `SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO` structure above.

Now my problem is: i want to access `UniqueProcessId` of each element in `array`, i thought to do do something like this `proc.Handles[i].UniqueProcessId` but this crashes.

So i figured i have to do something like line `var proc` above so something like this:

```
var procHandleAtIndex = ctypes.cast(buffer.addressOfElement(i), SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO.ptr).contents;
```

Now this avoid the crash but it is reading wrong thing. In other words I tested by giving `i=0` which `proc.Handles[0].UniqueProcessId != procHandleAtIndex.UniqueProcessId`. It turned out that `procHandleAtIndex.UniqueProcessId == proc.NumberOfHandles` when I passed `i=0`.

Please help me read elemetns in `Handles` from `buffer`

Thanks, I don't know any C I'm a javascript guy.

### REFERENCE

this is how it was succesfully accomplished in python ctypes:
https://github.com/offensive-security/exploit-database/blob/40b9adcb14b8307ea66f8b92d0371be80bbc70e4/platforms/windows/local/34272.py#L139

```
"""Return all the processes handles in the system atm."""
system_handle_information = SYSTEM_HANDLE_INFORMATION_EX()
size = DWORD (sizeof (system_handle_information))
while True:
    result = ntdll.NtQuerySystemInformation(
        SystemExtendedHandleInformation,
        byref(system_handle_information),
        size,
        byref(size)
    )
    result = signed_to_unsigned(result)
    if result == STATUS_SUCCESS:
        break
    elif result == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH:
        size = DWORD(size.value * 4)
        resize(system_handle_information, size.value)
    else:
        raise x_file_handles("NtQuerySystemInformation", hex(result))

pHandles = cast(
    system_handle_information.Handles,
    POINTER(SYSTEM_HANDLE_TABLE_ENTRY_INFO_EX * \
            system_handle_information.NumberOfHandles)
)
for handle in pHandles.contents:
    yield handle.UniqueProcessId, handle.HandleValue, handle.Object
```

Comment: Your sample code doesn't appear to be C or C++. Instead it looks to be JavaScript.

Comment: Thnks much for the read man. Yeah its javascript at top that uses js-ctypes. And bottom is python using python ctypes. But the logic to read the array is same. C people helped me in past to do stuff.

Comment: Perhaps, but in this case it looks like you'll need the help of people that know JavaScript and in particular js-ctypes. My knowledge of C/C++, Python, and Python's ctypes doesn't seem to be of any use. I would suggest updating your post to include the [tag:javascript] and [tag:jsctypes] tags. You should also update your example to include the JavaScript code where you allocate the buffer and make the call to `NtQuerySystemInformation`. In other words make your failing JavaScript example as complete as your working Python example.

Comment: Ok thanks man, its just the only people in the jsctypes area that help is me and two other guys who don't know how to do this :(, definitely javascript people wont know what this is :(